# find the lower rating of subsequent movies

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table **movies** and another called **directors** with the following attributes:

```
Movies               Director
------              -----------
title               name
director            country
year
genre
rating
```

I am trying to find the movies by the same director which had a lower rating than any subsequent movie from the same director. This is my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM movies m1
JOIN directors d ON m1.director=d.name 
WHERE EXISTS
    (
    SELECT * 
    FROM movies m2 
    WHERE (m1.rating<m2.rating 
    AND m1.year<m2.year)
    AND m1.director=m2.director
    );
```

I would expect results such as:

```
movie1    director1    rating-2   year1
movie2    director1    rating-4   year2
movie3    director1    rating-2   year4
movie4    director1    rating-4   year7
```

However, instead, I get:

```
movie1    director1    rating 2   year1
movie2    director1    rating 4   year2
movie3    director1    rating-4   year4
movie4    director1    rating-2   year7
```

I don't think this is the correct way of doing it. :(

Answer (score 0):

You want a local minimum . . . but in reverse.

```
select m.*
from (select m.*,
             min(m.rating) over (partition by m.director order by m.year desc rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as min_future_rating
      from movies m
     ) m
where rating < min_future_rating;
```